# How does a Certificate Authority send a private key safely to a consumer?

Tags: private-key, ca, certificate-authority

How does a Certificate Authority send the private key securely to their consumer?

Comment: I don't think private keys are sent. I believe public keys are sent instead. Although I'm a bit lost of what the 'consumer' might be. Is it the buyer of the Certificate? Or the visitor?

Comment: I'm feeling that this is a bit of a "let me google that for you" question. What research have you done into this question? What parts of the easily-accessible knowledge (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18951/secure-way-to-transfer-public-secret-key-to-second-computer, for instance) do you need help with?

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883438/where-is-private-key-when-using-ssl-stored

Comment: I read somewhere that certain cases Certificate Authority issues both private and public key. I was curious to know how does the CA send the private key to their customer safely?

Comment: Also if the CA is sending the private key to the customer, both parties know about the 'private key'. This means that the private key is no longer 'private' and that is a risk for the customer. (By customer I mean the person/entity who is going to use the digital certificate / who owns the private key)

Comment: In most cases the CA does not ever see the private key. However, section 6.1.2 of the ["Baseline Requirements Certificate Policy for the Issuance and Management of Publicly-Trusted Certificates"](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.4.1.pdf) says, in part, "If the CA or any of its designated RAs generated the Private Key on behalf of the Subscriber, then the CA SHALL encrypt the Private Key for transport to the Subscriber."